# Unit Testing of a static factory method containing logic

Tags: c#, unit-testing, factory

before I begin with my question I want to point out that I am aware that there are tons of similar questions on stack overflow. Unfortunately none of these questions helped me finding a good solution in my concrete scenario.

**The Problem:**

I want to write a unit test for a static factory method which contains logic. I am looking for a way to unit test this method even if it is static. If that is not possible maybe someone can point out a better design for my class under test. I also considered using IoC but couldn't see the advantage considering unit-testing.

**The Code:**

```
public class Db
{
    private XmlMapping mapping;

    public static Db<T> Create()
    {
        var mapping = XmlMapping.Create(typeOf(T).Name);
        return new Db(mapping);
    }

    private Db(XmlMapping mapping)
    {
        this.mapping = mapping;
    }
}

public class XmlMapping //class under test
{
    public static XmlMapping Create(string filename) //method under test
    {            
        try
        {
            ValidateFilename(filename);
            //deserialize xml to object of type XmlMapping
            var result = Deserialize(filename);
            if (result.IsInValid())
                throw Exception()
            return result; 
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new DbException();
        }
    }
}
```

The method *Create* which I want to unit test is within the class *XmlMapping*. This method serializes a xml file and generates an object of type XmlMapping. I tried to write a stub for the serialization part. But didn't want to call my Database Factory with a Mapping class in the constructor (constructor injection).

**Edit:**

My database factory is generic. The generic type is used to figure out which xml file should be louded i.e.: *typeOf(T) = Customer --> XmlMapping-File = Customer.xml*

**The Solution (Thx to Jeff!):**

```
public class XmlMapping : IMapping //class under test
{
    internal static Func<Type, IMapping> DeserializeHandler { get; set; }

    static XmlMapping()
    {
        DeserializeHandler = DeserializeMappingFor;
    }

    public static IMapping Create(Type type)
    {
        try
        {
            var mapping = DeserializeHandler(type);
            if (!mapping.IsValid())
                throw new InvalidMappingException();
            return mapping;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new DataException("Failed to load mapping configuration from xml file.", ex);
        }
    }

    internal XmlMapping(IMapping mapping)
    {
        this.Query = mapping.Query;
        this.Table = mapping.Table;
        this.Entity = mapping.Entity;
        this.PropertyFieldCollection = mapping.PropertyFieldCollection;
    }

    private XmlMapping() { }
}


[TestClass]
public class MappingTests //testing class
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Create_ValidDeserialization_ReturnsObjectInstance()
    {
        XmlMapping.DeserializeHandler = MakeFakeHandlerFor(MakeMappingStub());
        var result = XmlMapping.Create(typeof(ActivityDto));
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(XmlMapping));
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you communicating the the XmlMapping class the Xml file that you want deserialized?

Comment: ah I forgot that part ... I will edit my question

Comment: So, you're attempting to verify that "deserialize" is called with proper arguments?

Comment: I make a parameter validation, deserialize the object and check if the deserialization was successful. All surrounded by try - catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a fake action handler to assist in verifying the content of the call to deserialize.  Let's add a Func delegate property and default that to your serialize method.  Your XmlMapping class and test would like something like:

```
public class XmlMapping //class under test
{

    static XmlMapping()
    {
        // Default the handler to the normal call to Deserialize
        DeserializeHandler = Deserialize;
    }

    public static XmlMapping Create(string filename) //method under test
    {
        //deserialize xml to object of type XmlMapping
        //preudocode:
        var result = DeserializeHandler(string.Format("{0}.xml",filename));
        //...
        return result;
    }

    // Abstract indirection function to allow you to swap out Deserialize implementations
    internal static Func<string, XmlMapping> DeserializeHandler { get; set; }

    private static XmlMapping Deserialize(string fileName)
    {
        return new XmlMapping();
    }

}

public class CreateTests {

    public void CallingDeserializeProperly()
    {

        // Arrange
        var called = false;
        Func<string, XmlMapping> fakeHandler = (string f) =>
        {
            called = true; // do your test of the input and put your result here
            return new XmlMapping();
        };

        // Act
        XmlMapping.DeserializeHandler = fakeHandler;
        var m = XmlMapping.Create("test");

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(called);

    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Jeff this looks very interesting! I will give it a try tomorrow. Thanks for the effort. I appreciate it.

Comment: Buzz me if you have any further needs for unit test help - I'm @csharpfritz on twitter

Comment: Here be dragons! It may seem peculiar here that when testing Db.Create() you have to mock out some other hidden dependency (XmlMapping) but seems innocent if you inspect the code for Db. However, all subsequent objects further up the call hierarchy will also need this dependency mocked out. This is not a slippery slope, it's a cliff. All future tests will be fragile and unintelligible. Use a factory!

Comment: @bryan how would you have designed the class? I am already using a factory method so why is a stand alone factory better for this purpose?

Comment: Your factory method is static member of the Type, so anywhere the Type is used so is the possibility of using the factory -- this leads you to a scenario of anyone who uses the Type will also have preconditions in the tests: a pain point of brittleness. If you were to move to a MappingFactory<T> which is passed in through the constructor you can stub out the class out and control which classes need to instantiate your type versus ones that need to consume it.